# File.Copy hangs on corrupt file

Tags: c#, hard-drive, .net

I've been trying to copy files from an old drive to a new drive. Problem is, the old drive has (I can only assume) some corrupted places on the disk, and any attempt to read from some of these files results in what seems to be some kind of endless loop. There are quite a few problem files sprinkled throughout the files I want to copy, and when it hits the first one, my application just sits there doing nothing until I stop it. I was hoping I could get around this by writing a custom program to recurse through the directories, copy the files one by one, and catch any errors that pop up on individual copy operations, but it never gets to the point of throwing an error--just sits there and sits there and sits there. The only way to stop this is to physically turn off the problem hard drive--can't stop the program by trying to end the process or anything like that.

I'm somewhat puzzled as to how to proceed. Given that this kind of error is going to happen, is there any way to automate this process? Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: This is a kernel-mode issue.  I don't think there's anything you can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use the copy methods on the standard System.IO classes (Directory / DirectoryInfo / File / FileInfo)?

Have you tried to copy the files with a FileStream? To prevent those errors you can set a the ReadTimeout on the stream (stream.ReadTimeout). This way you get Exceptions when the Read() operation takes too long. And you should also get errors if a file can't be opened.

Comment: A little googling says you can only use that property with network reads, not local filesystem reads. I get a "Timeout not supported on this stream" error when I try your way, and everything fails. Nice idea though.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. How about: Derive from FileStream; implement the ReadTimeout and override Read(..) that it throws exception's when it takes too long?

Answer (score 4):

This can happen when the HD is extremely corrupt and it takes a very long time for the HD to respond. Usually when you are a CRC error is when this happens and on large files with lots of sectors screwed.

You should look into using lower level methods of viewing sectors then you will have more control when to stop.

There are programs though that are designed to do exactly what you want that might be easier to use(just search google for data recovery). Some are going to have special features that are more likely to recover your data. Some are quite advanced with special algorithms and such.

Answer (score 0):

You should look out for a data recovery tool and not for some tipps to get a robust copy process in C#...

If your old drive is not broken (makes clung clung noises) then you should try to recovery the file system with [chkdsk](http://www.vnr.de/b2b/computer/pruefung-der-festplatte-mit-chkdsk.html) .

If there are problems which chkdsk can not handle, you need a data recovery tool like  [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) or any other (try google 'data recovery' or 'copy files from corrupt disc').

Comment: That's a Unix program? I'm on Windows.

Comment: have you tried chkdsk first? It's the windows built in tool for correcting the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I think CBD(Copy Bad Disk) is exactly what you need: copy files on bad sectors without hang or stop, log position of unreadable bytes,etc.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble across this old thread like me, having had a comparable problem when copying some larger files (~1GB) over a wireless network connection: My WLAN adapter has a driver setting "Multimedia/Gaming Environment". When this was set to "Enable", large files often got corrupted when copied over the WLAN. After setting "Multimedia/Gaming Environment" to "Disable" the problem went away.